# Get only one of the current categories

Tags: categories

On post pages Im using the below code to display links to other posts from the current category.

My problem is when the current post is in more than 1 category it will display posts from the first category only.

I want to control which current categories it shows posts from by excluding certain categories Ids (e.g. 29, 35)

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
global $post;
$category = get_the_category($post->ID);
$category = $category[0]->cat_ID;
$myposts = get_posts(array('numberposts' => 5, 'offset' => 0, 'category__in' => array($category),  'post_status'=>'publish', 'order'=>'ASC' ));
foreach($myposts as $post) :
setup_postdata($post);
?>
<li>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "rw_post_type", true); ?></a>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); 

?>
</ul>
<?php
```

Answer (score 1):

[`get_the_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category) should be returning all of the categories for your post, but you are only picking one of them, the first one, when you do this-- `$category = $category[0]->cat_ID;`. Instead of that line try:

```
$allcats = array();
foreach ($category as $cat) {
  if (29 != $cat->cat_ID && 35 != $cat->cat_ID) {
    $allcats[] = $cat->cat_ID;
  }
}
$myposts = get_posts(
  array(
    'numberposts' => 5, 
    'offset' => 0, 
    'category__in' => $allcats,  
    'post_status'=>'publish', 'order'=>'ASC' 
));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but maybe my question was not clearer enough. I understand I am only picking one category, and this is what I am aiming to do. Most of the time the category I want is the first category but occasionally it will not be because categories 29 and 35 will be first. I want to update the code so that it ignores these two categories. Does this make sense?

Comment: Excluding those categories is easy. Updated the code.